# Python: How to convert a long datetime string to required format

Tags: python, datetime

I have this time here : `2017-08-05T05:21:10.6582942Z`
And I want to convert it into `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`
I can do that using some funky methods such as :

```py
date = "2017-08-05T05:21:10.6582942Z"
new_date = date[:11] + " " + date[12:][:-9]
```

But is there any way I can do something cleaner with `datetime` or some libraries made for this specific purpose ?

Comment: `datetime.strptime(…).strftime(…)`…?

Comment: To parse more than 6 digits of fractional seconds "automatically", [dateutil's parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) could be an option. Note however that Python's datetime is limited to microsecond precision, so those additional digits will be ignored. You'd have to use a third-party library to consider them.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#) library with the [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method (for parsing) and the [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) method (for formatting), this can be accomplished with no splits and limited slicing as:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

date = '2017-08-05T05:21:10.6582942Z'
output = dt.strptime(date[:-2], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

**Output:**

```
'2017-08-05 05:21:10'
```

**Note:**
The slice is needed to remove the last two characters from the string date, as the `%f` (fractional seconds) formatter only accepts six decimal values, and your string contains seven decimal values.

Per the [formatting documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

> `%f`: Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded to 6 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Start with importing `datetime`:

```
import datetime as dt
```

Convert `string` to `datetime` object:

```
date = "2017-08-05T05:21:10.6582942Z"
new_date = dt.datetime.strptime(date[:-2], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f") # -2 slice to since %f only accepts 6 digits.
```

Format `datetime` object as string:

```
format_date = dt.datetime.strftime(new_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # returns your format
```

However, looking at your code it feels your `date` is already formatted and you don't require the last `.strftime()` usage.

Comment: If you process the string like that, why not simply replace the T with a space ?

Comment: Well, `.strptime()` cannot forge inputs and takes everything passed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284850/datetime-strptime-set-format-to-ignore-trailing-part-of-string

Comment: @FObersteiner here the motive is to make them understand `.strftime()` and `.strptime()` rather than just giving a solution.

Comment: I think that's a good answer, but I was wondering if I can do that without parsing it by hand. I don't want to create a datetime object of something I've already parsed before. I want datetime to parse it for me (because this is a simple example, but I have more complexe time to parse and I don't want to make some mistakes by parsing it myself)

Comment: Checked the revised answer @Vincent.